# Ajax call at Laravel route that returns an json encoded array containing dates for ChartJS labels

Tags: jquery, html, json, laravel, html-entities

I have a Laravel 5.7 project, with ajax and ChartJS.

At page load, I am making an ajax call to "**action_route**", which returns the labels for my ChartJS. The php function is json encoding an array of labels, and the ajax decodes them.

```
function get_data($year) {
    $test = \DB::select( \DB::raw("
        SELECT 
            DATE_FORMAT(date_for,'%c/%y') AS 'month',
            col1,
            col2,
            col3
        FROM test
        WHERE
            AND YEAR(date_for) = '" . $year . "'
        GROUP BY month
        ORDER BY month ASC
    ") );

    return $test;
}

public function action_route() {
   $data = self::get_data(2018);
   foreach($data as $x) {
      $labels[] = $x->month;
   }
}

return view('/test/get_data', [
     'labels' => json_encode($labels)
]);
```

> DATE_FORMAT(date_for,'%c/%y') AS 'month' - Because I need dates if this format: '01/18', '02/18' etc.

In template:

```
var labels = JSON.parse('{{ $labels }}');
```

**The Problem**
This is what get's put into html.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `{{ }}` laravel will escape the data it displaying. To stop it escaping the data you should wrap it in `{!! !!}` instead i.e.

```
var labels = JSON.parse('{!! $labels !!}');
```

For more information you can check out the [Docs](http://var%20labels%20=%20JSON.parse('%7B%7B%20$labels%20%7D%7D');)

Comment: The Chart appears now but it's still not ok, I'm getting labels like: "1%2B18", "10%2B18". I think this is some sort on HTML issue that it's converting characters

Comment: IT WORKs - sorry for the previous comment. I was trying something on my own that was breaking that. THank you

Comment: @JohnDoe It's alright, I'm glad I could help. Just out of curiosity, how come you're using raw queries instead of Eloquent? Do you have an Eloquent model set up for your `test` table?

Comment: Because it's a very complex query and it's impossible using Eloquent, this is just a plain example, the actual query is huge. ( I have model & controller )

Comment: @JohnDoe Ah fair enough.